# Function array in Java?

Tags: java, jump-table

Maybe I think to much in C, but I don't see a solution how to solve this properly in java.
I get a response from my server which sends a string like this:

```
command params <xml...>
```

The client receives that string and extracts the command. Now I would like to call a function which knows how to handle the command. On the C side the solution is obvious. I implemented an array with the command name and associated function pointes, so I can simply loop through the array and call the function.

Is there some way to do this on Java as well? I don't know that I could call a function based on the name. So currently I see the following options:

1. Do a series of `if(command.euqals(COMMAND)`
2. For each command I could create a separate object which I can store in an array (very messy).
3. Use reflection, so I can have a map with the function names vs. command names.

Are there any other options?

The if statements is not the best IMO, but at least it allows for compiler errors and typechecking. Using reflection is at least more elegant because I can loop and extend it more easily, but of course, it means that I can see only runtime errors if I misstype the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second idea is idiomatic. Use a `Map<String, Runnable>` to store the command names and corresponding code, then `commands.get(commandName).run()` to execute one.

Don't be afraid of creating classes! It may make your code start out more verbose, but it's much easier to write a class and never have to worry about it again than to do the same with a `switch` or `if ... else if ...`. If your commands ever become more complicated than single methods (maybe `toString()`, `undo()`...), you'll be increasingly glad that you used polymorphism instead of conditionals.

Comment: I thought it a bit messy, because I would have to create a lot of classes just to performa a single task, which it can not even perform itself, instead it has to update the GUI etc.. On the ohter hand, maybe it is not such a bad idea, I have to see what impact it has on the GUI code.

Comment: I don't see this as messy at all; it's the cornerstone of polymorphism!

Comment: The more I thought about this approach, the more I like it. My initial idea was that I would have hundreds of tiny classes, but after reconsidering the arguments, it's not as bad and it definitely has the advantages you mentioned.

Comment: It's even better now that you can create anonymous classes. `new Command(){ run() { /* process command */ } }` -
  this can be an array of `Command` where that is an interface class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this type of problem in the past using the following approach, it might be suitable in your case:

Have a standard interface:

```
public interface Executable {
    public String getCommandName();
    public void execute(String[] params, String xml);
}
```

and x number of implementations:

```
public class SaveExecutable implements Executable {
    private static final String COMMAND_NAME = "SAVE";
    public String getCommandName() {
        return COMMAND_NAME;
    }

    public void execute(String[] params, String xml) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Then store the implementations in a HashMap for lookup:

```
HashMap<String, Executor> executors = new HashMap<>();
executors.put("SAVE", new SaveExecutable());
```

Then you can have a method to handle generic commands (validation and array trimming omitted):

```
public void handleCommand(String[] command) {
    executors.get(command[0]).execute(command);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only one file, you can make it with `enum`.

Try something like this :

```
    public class Command {

      public enum CommandName {

        UNDO,
        PRINT,
        RUN
      }

      public static void execute(String command, String[] params, String xml) {
        try {
          CommandName cname = CommandName.valueOf(command);

          switch (cname) {
            case UNDO:
               undo (params, xml);
              break;
            case PRINT:
              //
              break;
          }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
          // Unknown command
        }
      }

      public static void undo (String[] params, String xml) {
         // ....
      }
    }
```

Run the command :

```
    Command.execute(command, params, xml);
```

Comment: Remember that Java enums can have methods - you could declare an abstract `doExecute` and instead of the `switch` just do `cname.doExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently was shown a functional *trick* that simple though it is, is quite effective: "wrap" a function or set of functions with another function.

Below is an example of code I have written in order to show this *trick*.
My example only serves out one function for one command, but it can easily be extended to a bunch of functions returned if needs be (hence the inclusion of the Guava Mutlimap type which can be used)...I return an Optional so when a command does not match, it "safely" returns a null; the Contact and ContacUnit are domain types which all extend an Organization type...this should then make the below code make sense.

```
package com.xxx.component;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.xxx.domain.Contact;
import com.xxx.domain.ContactUnit;
import com.xxx.domain.Organization;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

/**
 * This serves up the functions used for the domain
 * to validate itself.
 * Created by beezerbutt on 06/04/2017.
 */
public class MapSetDomainFunctionFactory {

    public static final Function<String, Optional<Organization>> toContactFromCwid = s-> Optional.ofNullable(s).map(Contact::new);
    public static final Function<String, Optional<Organization>> toContactUnitFromKey = s-> Optional.ofNullable(s).map(ContactUnit::new);

    public static final Function<String, Function<String, Optional<Organization>>> commandToFunctions = command -> {
        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("toContactFromCwid")) {
            return MapSetDomainFunctionFactory.toContactFromCwid;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

}

To make life easier, I am including the Domain class code:

```
/**
 * Created by beezerbutt on 06/04/2017.
 */
public class Contact implements Organization {
}
public class ContactUnit implements Organization {
}
public interface Organization {
}
```

Below is a snapshot of a Spock test I ran to prove that the code works:
[image]